# My trigger doesn't work

Tags: triggers

```
CREATE TRIGGER `update_data` AFTER UPDATE on `employee`
FOR each row
BEGIN
    IF (NEW.salary = 1.1 * OLD.salary) THEN
        INSERT INTO HIGH_SALARY_RAISE 
        VALUES(empno, OLD.salary, NEW.salary);
    END IF;
END$$
```

Create a table named `HIGH_SALARY_RAISE`. It should have the following columns:

```
HIGH_SALARY_RAISE EMPNO CHAR(6) NOT NULL
PREV_SAL  DECIMAL(9,2) NOT NULL
NEW_SAL  DECIMAL(9,2) NOT NULL
UPDATE_USER  VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL DEFAULT  SYSTEM_USER
UPDATE_TIME  DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT  GETDATE()
```

Create a trigger so that when the `EMPLOYEE` table is updated, if the new salary exceeds the previous value by 10% or more, then a new row should be inserted  into `HIGH_SALARY_RAISE`.

Comment: Triggers are evil! Avoid as much as you can

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Triggers are **highly vendor-specific** - please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.